# Save row's position without a positioning column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

Here is the table structure:

```
Id | Description
1  | Test1
2  | Test2
```

In asp.net forms, I have two fields for inserting values for this table.

As I can't add a new column for memorizing the position of rows, do you have any ideas for accomplishing this functionality?

**Edit:**

I don't know whether stored procedure can do this or not.

Comment: for what purpose you need this position value?

Comment: This is for displaying the rows with order in front office.

Comment: can't u use order by on Id column ?

Comment: No, because the values in first field could be inserted after the second field.

Comment: Does the position have a functional meaning or is it just a "personal" configuration option?

Comment: You've said you can't add a new column (why?). Could you add a new table?

Comment: I can't add a new column because of the database can't be modified temporarily. So i can't modify the database, ie: add columns, add tables etc.

Comment: The position is already decided by the input field in asp form. For example: when user input values in the second field, the position will be 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could just append the order value as a suffix in the description, and when you read out the value you would remove the suffix when displaying it.

If your order is "Test2","Test1","Test3":

```
Id | Description
1  | Test1-2
2  | Test2-1
3  | Test3-3
```

Of course this is a horrible hack and you should rather add another column in your db table. But if you are unable to do this, this is the only solution I see.

Comment: Yes, this maybe a solution for my question. I couldn't find another method for that. Thanks!